# How can I change Calendar range selection colour in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker, uicolor

I want to change the background color of selection date from the first to last date dark and between light colour. I've researched other questions but it's not working. All I want to do is just change colour of start and end date. I fine it hard to believe that I can't do such a seemingly simple task. I am eagerly trying to change color in range date but getting difficulty. I am sharing an image for reference.

[image]

Comment: please add some code

Comment: How are you setting the colours for the range? If you are able to set the colours for these range, all you have to do is to check for start and end date for which you set the dark colour and set the lighter one for the rest.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello @Hiral Jahlani , could you please share some code, also have you used in pod for this?